# Can I keep my GTAV triathlon clothing?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've just tried the really really long triathlon event in GTAV (the one near Trevor's initial safehouse) and killed a spectator at the last checkpoint so I forfeited the mission and it finished with me still wearing my red & white triathlon onesie.  When I go home to change my clothes I don't seem to have the onesie available, does that mean if I change outfit I'll lose it?

I'd quite like to keep it, it looks suitably crazy for Trevor!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you'll lose it. You have to fully complete the triathlon in order to unlock the onesie permanently. For now just run around until the next race.

Answer (score 1):

You do not get the triathlon outfit for anybody.

I have completed all 3 events with all three characters and no outfit was unlocked.